# A tetrahedron with edge length of $3$ can be made using $x$ tetrahedrons and $y$ octahedrons with edge lengths of $1?$

Tags: geometry

**Question $1$.** A tetrahedron with edge length of $N=3$ can be made using $x$ tetrahedrons with edge length of $1$ and $y$ octahedrons with edge length of $1.$ Find "all possible" $x$ and $y$.

**Question $2.$** An octahedron with edge length of $N=3$ can be made using $z$ tetrahedrons with edge length of $1$ and $w$ octahedrons with edge length of $1.$ Find "all possible" $z$ and $w$.

**Question $3.$** Find generalized solution for $N\geq3$.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Making sketches may help; can you see how a regular octahedron sits inside a regular tetrahedron, leaving some number of regular tetrahedra?

Comment: I am wondering if there is some mathmatical explanation for the solution.. I think I mean rather algebraic solution.

Comment: Since counting is straightforward here, using algebra seems like unnecessary baggage. That said, if you were interested in generalizing to tetrahedra and octahedra of edge length $n > 2$, algebra might be appropriate. And if this is homework, your instructor may have a particular method in mind.

Comment: Okay. Then how can you guarantee that there is only one solution even for $n=3$?

Comment: This is not a homework. This was a problem from a math contest. And clear answer was not known for this one. That's why I asked here. I'm not a student.

Comment: For general $N \ge 1$, under some mild assumption how the tetrahedron and octahedron are packed together, one can show that
$$(x,y)_N = \left( \frac{N}{3}(N^2+2), \frac{N}{6}(N^2-1) \right)$$
Question 1 is basically settled. For question 2, one can show that one
possible value of $(z,w)$ is given by the formula
$$(x,y)_{2N} - 4(x,y)_N = \left( \frac{4N}{3}(N^2-1), 
\frac{N}{3}(2N^2+1)\right)$$
However, I've no idea whether this exhaust all possibilities of $(z,w)$.

In particular, $(x_3,y_3) = (11,4)$ and $(z_3,w_3)$ can be $(32,19)$.

Comment: Thanks achille, I'll have to spend some time on thinking about your solution.

Comment: An [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/V6eyB.jpg) showing 
how to pack tetrahedron/octahedron of side 1 into a tetrahedron/octahedron of side 3.
If one assume the smaller tetrahedron/octahedron are packed in such a way such that facets are attached to facets, then the number of tetrahedron/octahedron
attached to any inner vertices are determined by where the vertex are. If you count the number
of different type of vertices and use the relations $x+4y = n^3, z+4w = 4n^3$ (obtained by balancing the volumes), you can show $(x,y)$ and $(z,w)$ are given by the formula in my previous comment.